# Else statement in my case... Im a noob

Tags: java

I need help with my code. I'm a noob at java but hope to one day be really good at it.

```
static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   public static void main(String[] args){
      Lottery();
   }

   public static void Lottery(){
      System.out.println("Welcome to Jacks Lottery!");
      System.out.println("If the Numbers match... You Win! It will pick a random number of the money you win!");
      int random = (int)(Math.random() * 50 + 1);
      int r = (int)(Math.random() * 50 + 1);
      int m = (int)(Math.random() * 1000 + 1);
      System.out.println("The First Number is: " + random);
      System.out.println("The Second Number is: " + r);

      if (random == r);
      System.out.println("You Win! You get: $" + m);
      if (random != r);
      System.out.println("You lose :( Try again?");
   }
}
```

How would I make an else sign in between these?:

```
if (random == r);
   System.out.println("You Win! You get: $" + m);
if (random != r);
   System.out.println("You lose :( Try again?");
```

Don't criticize and say this is a nooby little game because I know it is. I'm just making a fun little thing to show my family and wow them.

Comment: if your are a java newbie, use braces `{` with control flow statements. it will save your life without you knowing it.

Answer (score 2):

remove that semicolon from `if`

```
if (random == r);
```

`;` means end of statement so next statement will get executed regardless of condition

also switch to `if` `else` instead of 2 condition checks

```
if(condition) {

} else {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

at the end if statetment you must use '{' no ';'

```
if (random == r){
       System.out.println("You Win! You get: $" + m);
}
else{
      System.out.println("You lose :( Try again?");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (random == r){
   System.out.println("You Win! You get: $" + m);
}
else{
   System.out.println("You lose :( Try again?");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider your following code line

```
  if (random == r); // when your if condition match it will execute nothing
                    // since there is no code block between close ) and ;
  System.out.println("You Win! You get: $" + m);
```

You can use following

```
  if (random == r) // remove ;
  System.out.println("You Win! You get: $" + m);
```

Now your code works. But as a good practice should use `{}` for `if`

```
 if (random == r){
 System.out.println("You Win! You get: $" + m);
 }
```

Again you can change your following code too

```
  if (random == r);
  System.out.println("You Win! You get: $" + m);
  if (random != r);
  System.out.println("You lose :( Try again?");
```

Corrected version

```
  if (random == r){
   System.out.println("You Win! You get: $" + m);
  }else{    
   System.out.println("You lose :( Try again?");
  }
```

Comment: ill just stick to the "{" :)